# Replacing a fragments View after onCreateView has run

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a Fragment with two view modes, a edit mode and a read only mode. The user can switch modes by moving between statuses that are selected in a spinner available in both modes.

When the fragment is created I pick the a read only or edit layout to inflate based on the status of the object I an managing. Once a user picks a new status the mode may switch from read only to edit mode. When this happens I need to replace the edit view with the read only view.

How do I replace the existing View in the fragment? In an Activity I would call setContentView with the layout I want to use.

I've tried:

- Invalidating the View, but onCreateView isn't called again.
- Replacing the fragment with a fragment transaction, but it does not change the layout.

Note: This is for Android 4.0 and I cannot use the compatibility library.

Comment: Why aren't you using two fragments?  Seems like it would be much easier.  Just use .replace to swap them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep everything within one fragment:

I'm not completely sure how exactly your layout looks, but I guess I'd just throw both layouts in a [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) and change it's displayed child depending on what's selected.

Sample fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ..>
    <Spinner ../>

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" ..>
        <ReadOnlyLayout />
        <EditLayout />
    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can simply use [`setDisplayedChild()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setDisplayedChild%28int%29) to switch between the two layouts, depending on which state you have.

```
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) getView().findViewById(R.id.flipper);
vf.setDisplayedChild(1);
```

Note that child indices start with 0.

Two independent fragments can also be used *(as suggested by Barak)*. I guess it's merely a design choice.

Comment: ViewFlipper was exactly what I needed... Thank you.