# How would i change a fragment layout after a ListItem has been clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

So i'm trying to change my `Fragment` layout once a `ListItem` has been selected from the `ListView`. I'm not quite sure how i would go about doing this though. Here's the basis of the code i'm using...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_d, container, false);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // Getting list item index
            int listIndex = position;

            ((IndexListener) getActivity()).onIndexSelected(listIndex);

        }
    });


    return rootView;

}
```

I have intentionally removed sections of the code to keep it as relevant to the question as possible.

**Summary**

So how would i modify `rootView` to return a different layout format other than `R.layout.fragment_list_d`, once a `ListItem` has been clicked?

Comment: You have to inflate another layout, whats the problem?

Comment: I don't know how i would inflate another layout once a `ListItem` has been clicked. Would i still have to use rootView?

Comment: I  think i understand you, you are looking for setContentView but in fragment... You have this solution (i dont like it, tell me if you dont too) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951958/replacing-a-fragments-view-after-oncreateview-has-run

Comment: Yeah, i'm trying not to mess around with the XML as much. And yes, i'm trying to set a new content view in the `onItemClick` function.

Comment: You could clear rootView then inflate then addView but you will have to share the root layout do you understand?

Comment: Can you give me a general example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only option if you dont want to make a fragment replace is to get the parent, remove your previous content and add the new.

First store rootView in a class field so you can get its reference once you have passed by onCreateView, then do:

```
ViewGroup parentView =rootView.getParent();
parentView.removeView(rootView);
View newRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newlayout, parentView, false);
parentView.addView(newRootView);
```

Something like this **should** work (not tested, just wrote from my head)

Hope this helps.